# Add custom column to Users admin panel

Tags: wordpress, types, field, admin

I added custom columns but now I don't know how to get the date from the fields to show... and I have an error in my code. Can someone help?

Thanks

Here's the code :

```
function new_modify_user_table( $column ) { 
    $column['les-non-specialistes'] = 'Non-spécialiste';
    $column['specialistes'] = 'Spécialiste'; return $column; 
} 

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) { 
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id ); 

    switch ($column_name) { 
        case 'les-non-specialistes' : return get_the_author_meta( 'les-non-specialistes', $user_id ); 
        break; 
        case 'specialistes' : return ''; 
            break; 
        default: 
    } 

    return $return;
} 

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The $return variable wasn't declared.

```
function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $return = '';

    $user = get_userdata( $user_id ); 

switch ($column_name) { 
    case 'les-non-specialistes' : 
        return get_the_author_meta( 'les-non-specialistes', $user_id ); 
    break; 
    case 'specialistes' : 
        return ''; 
        break; 
    default: 
} 

return $return;
```

}

Comment: What am I suppose to put in the var $return = ''; ? Because I get an error there...

Comment: Sorry, thought this was javascript. Try removing the var keyword. I'll edit my answer.